# nano.specs not found in arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, arm, stm32, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and I need to use arm-none-eabi-gcc version 4.8.2 ( I know it is old, but i have to use this version)
So I successfully install this library with below files:

```
binutils-arm-none-eabi_2.24-2ubuntu2+4_amd64.deb
gcc-arm-none-eabi_4.8.2-14ubuntu1+6_amd64.deb
libcloog-isl4_0.18.2-1_amd64.deb
libisl10_0.12.2-1_amd64.deb
libnewlib-arm-none-eabi_2.1.0-3_all.deb
libnewlib-dev_2.1.0-3_all.deb
multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libmpfr4_3.1.6-1_amd64.deb
```

Than I checked my gcc-arm-none-eabi version like this :

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version

 arm-none-eabi-gcc (4.8.2-14ubuntu1+6) 4.8.2
    Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Than I am trying to compile the source code for stm32f4 with makefile.

If I use the `-specs=nano.specs` in makefile I get below error:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: nano.specs: No such file or directory
```

But if I dont use `-specs=nano.specs` command in makefile I can compile successfuly, but I need to use `-specs=nano.specs` command how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Did nano exist at that time?